# Access VBA to import dynamic excel spreadsheets as text

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am looking for a way to use access vba to import an entire excel spreadsheet as text. The hard part with this one is that the import needs to be dynamic. I know that normally an import can easily be accomplished via a saved import or using a `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` method, but unfortunately those do not suit my needs as the number of columns and certain headernames may change between files (these are files from clients and therefore I have no control over how they come in). Obviously performance is not a priority for this method.

Sudo-code:

```
Dim db AS DAO.Database
Dim file_to_import AS String

Set db = CurrentDb
Set file_to_import = "C:/Foo/bar/Access/Imports/FORIMPORT.xlsx"

'Read headers of spreadsheet into array
Loop through header row (A1:ZZ1) and create an array

'Create table creation string based on array
Creation_String = "CREATE TABLE TBL_Import ([Array_Element1]  TEXT(255), [Array_Element2]  TEXT(255), [Array_Element3]  TEXT(255), ...etc, etc"

'Create TBL_Import
CurrentDb.Execute Creation_String

'Import data
'(Imports data from file_to_import into TBL_Import)
```

Somewhat similar to this question, may be able to use this as a starting point:
[[MS Access VBA script to interface with Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999444/ms-access-vba-script-to-interface-with-excel][1])

Thanks in advance for the help with this. I know some code but obviously I am still learning the ins and outs of VBA.

Comment: Review http://www.accessmvp.com/KDSnell/EXCEL_Import.htm

Answer (score 0):

The easy workaround is not to import the sheet but *link* it.

Then you have an attached (linked) table you can use as source in a simple select query where you modify and/or convert values.

Now, use this query for your further processing.